# Building a string while looping though the Datatable,inserting, then resetting the string and repeat

Tags: c#, linq

I need to build a string from a DataTable,insert it then repeat for each unique value in column1.

```
*column1    *column2   *Column3    (Column to insert)
   1            a          b           a|b|c|d
   1            c          d           a|b|c|d
   2            e          f           e|f|g|h
   2            g          h           e|f|g|h
```

this is what I have so far,

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {
       pvar += dr["Column2"].ToString() + "|" + dr["Column3"].ToString();
        }
       System.Data.DataColumn newColumn = new System.Data.DataColumn
                                          ("pvar", typeof(System.String));
               newColumn.DefaultValue = pvar;
               table.Columns.Add(newColumn);
               pvar = "";
        }
```

Problem I have is that I'm getting:

```
 *column1    *column2   *Column3    (Column to insert)
   1            a          b           a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h
   1            c          d           a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h
   2            e          f           a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h
   2            g          h           a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically doing everything backwards. You want something like this:

```
DataColumn newColumn = new System.Data.DataColumn("pvar", typeof(System.String));
table.Columns.Add(newColumn);

foreach (DataRow currentRow in table.Rows)
{
    var pvar = table.AsEnumerable() 
        .Where (r => r["Column1"].Equals(currentRow["Column1"]))
        .Select (r => string.Format("{0}|{1}", r["Column2"], r["Column3"]))
        .Aggregate((s, t) => string.Format("{0}|{1}", s, t));
    currentRow["pvar"] = pvar;
}
```

Add the column at the beginning, and then set that value on each column.

What your code did was, build a string containing the values from every row in the database, and then add a column to the table that contains that big string on every row.

Comment: Thank you, very much for straightening me out. this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want although not tested.

```
var grouped = from gTable in table.AsEnumerable()
                group gTable by new { groupId = gTable["Column1"] } into groupby
                select new
                {
                    Value = groupby.Key,
                    ColumnValues = groupby
                };

foreach (var key in grouped)
{
    pvar = "";
    foreach (var columnValue in key.ColumnValues)
    {
        pvar += columnValue["Column2"].ToString() + "|" + columnValue["Column3"].ToString();
    }
}
```